# Alternative to mapping network drives

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We have used all our drives for network shares. What is the alternative for mappning drive letters to network shares? GPO, mount points, something else?

It has to be automated and based on user group, certain users see only certain number of network shares. We use DFS, GPO, and AD in our environment.

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer is going to be to restructure how you use shares. I realise that's not what you want to hear, but that's pretty much it. You can dump shortcuts to UNC paths onto a user's desktop but I don't expect that to be very manageable as a solution.

Comment: In addition you can use item-level targeting with GPO mapped drive preferences to control who gets which mapped drives added.  However, if you are using all of them you really need to rethink your organizational structure.